# SQL Server : use a transaction in the then clause of merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a `merge` statement, when not matched, I need to insert into target table and update another table. How can I achieve this?

```
merge table1 as TARGET
using table2 as SOURCE ON <conditions>

when not matched by target
    then
       /*--------can i do this?---------*/
       BEGIN TRANSACTION
          insert (columnnames) values(v1,..., vn)   /*insert into target*/

          update source 
          set column1 = value1      /*update source*/
       END TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: What is the way to execute two statements in the "then" clause?

Comment: I would use transactions and `if`.  I'm not sure that `merge` has a particular advantage here.

Comment: Your question and the title are conflicting. Are you asking about a transaction or about having 2 statements?

Comment: I need to have a transaction with two statements in the then clause.

Answer (score 4):

The whole `merge` statement is atomic (either the whole statement completes or the whole statement gets rolled back) so that you don't need to create a transaction.

Here's an example [from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target
USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET Name = source.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
   VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)
   OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;
```

Comment: i need to execute two statements in the "then" clause.

Comment: can i write an "update source" statement in the output clause in "when not matched" ??

Comment: No you won't be able to do that directly in `merge`.  You could potentially add a trigger to the table you're inserting that would do the update.  Or, you could `begin transaction` before `merge` and then use the `output` to know what to update after `merge` and before `end transaction`.